# Table generated from DataTable do not have a layout style

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, datatables

I am using DataTables to display my json data in html page, it works however the table I get has no styling. (see image). I tried adding css styling with width value equal to 80%, 100%, etc. But nothing happened.

Note: There is nothing wrong with displaying json data to the datatable. I already did it except that the layout is ugly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7ne9.png)

These are the CDN that I have in my header file:

```
<!--Ajax CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script-->

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Data Tables -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I tried removing the datatables bootstrap but it is still the same.

This is the HTML code where I display my table:

```html
<div>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="subjects_table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Offer #</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Units</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: please add the datatable cdn

Comment: Please add your code to the question. It looks like you have another library which is interfering with the Datatables CSS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I already edited my post showing the CDN in my header file.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Thank you for those who took their time and shared their inputs. I realized I made a silly mistake. The CDN's I've used caused the error. I removed all the DataTabes CDN I previously used and replaced it with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```